# Concatenate two array of arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, concatenation

I have an array of arrays, for example

```
a = [array([len(20)]),
     array([len(20)])]

b = [array([len(20)]),
     array([len(15)])]
```

`len(20)` refers to 20 objects/numbers the array contains.

However, when I try,

```
final_array = np.concatenate((a,b))
```

I get the error,

`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`
due to one of the array's being `len(15)` in `array b`.

**How do I join these two array of arrays together?**

**EDIT:** Suppose I have all the array's to be of `len(20)` inside `b`, then when I concatenate I get the shape of `final_array` to be `(4,20)`. But for my case, since there is one array with `len(15)`, I don't know if it is possible at all in the first place.

Comment: Join together how? What shape of array do you want to end up with?

Comment: suppose I have all the array's to be of `len(20)` inside `b`, then when I concatenate I get the `shape (4,20)`. But for my case, since there is one array with `len(15)`, I don't know if it is possible at all in the first place.

Comment: What does `len(20)` mean? For me that raises a `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: They contain 20 objects/numbers

Comment: You can't even make b a proper 2D numpy array, not speaking about joining a and b.

Comment: If you'd tried to run your code it would have faulted with a `TypeError` upon parsing `len(20)`. If you give some actual code, we might have an actual answer.

Comment: @user3397243 If I understand your (pseudo-)code correctly, `a` and `b` are lists of numpy arrays, not 2D numpy arrays, as @elzell was noting. If this is the case, maybe something like `final_array = a+b` could do the trick?

Comment: Replace this `len(20)` pseudo-code with actual examples that we can run with cut-n-paste.  We need to see exactly what your arrays look like, without depending on your description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your description your case looks like:

```
In [344]: a=[np.arange(5),np.arange(5)]
In [345]: b=[np.arange(5),np.arange(3)]
In [346]: a
Out[346]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]
In [347]: b
Out[347]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2])]
In [348]: np.concatenate((a,a))
Out[348]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [349]: np.concatenate((a,a),axis=1)
Out[349]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

But if I use `(a,b)` instead, it complains about the dimensions not being equal.

The behavior of `concatenate` is clearer when the inputs are themselves arrays.  Here they are lists of arrays.

Applying `np.array` to `a` produces a 2 row array.  `np.concatenate((a,))` does the same thing.

```
In [352]: np.array(a)
Out[352]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

But trying that on `b` produces an `object` array, because the 2 elements are unequal in size.  This is basically just a list in a `array` wrapper.

```
In [353]: np.array(b)
Out[353]: array([array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2])], dtype=object)
```

What does it mean to join `a` and `b` together?  Start with figuring out what you want an array version of `b` to look like.

```
In [361]: np.concatenate(b)
Out[361]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2])
```

Example using `np.pad` to ensure all elements of `b` are long enough:

```
In [370]: b1=[np.pad(i,(0,5-i.shape[0]),mode='constant') for i in b]
In [371]: b1
Out[371]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0])]
In [372]: np.array(b1)
Out[372]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]])
In [373]: np.concatenate((a,b1))
Out[373]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0]])
```